# Rsyslog output in GELF

Tags: logging, syslog, rsyslog, graylog

rsyslog is powerful, but its docs aren't that explicit. I can't figure out how to parse a log file and route it directly to Graylog in [GELF](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.0/pages/gelf.html) format.

I have found bits of documentation about [outputing gelf in rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/tutorials/gelf_forwarding.html) but I'm not sure how to proceed.

So far, it tried to place the below conf in `/etc/rsyslog.d/01-access.conf` but that doesn't seem to work…

```
template(name="gelf" type="list") {
    constant(value="{\"version\":\"1.1\",")
    constant(value="\"host\":\"")
    property(name="hostname")
    constant(value="\",\"short_message\":\"")
    property(name="msg" format="json")
    constant(value="\",\"timestamp\":\"")
    property(name="timegenerated" dateformat="unixtimestamp")
    constant(value="\",\"level\":\"")
    property(name="syslogseverity")
    constant(value="\"}")
}

input(type="imfile"
      File="/var/log/apache2/access.log"
      Tag="apache-access"
)

if $programname == 'apache-access' then {
    action(
        type="omfwd"
        Target="GRAYLOG-IP"
        Port="12201"
        Protocol="tcp"
        template="gelf"
    )
    stop
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You encounter this issue because sending via tcp is not working with rsyslog due to Gelf's null-byte message delimiter spec. 
From the official rsyslog documentation: (http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/tutorials/gelf_forwarding.html)
"Please note that the case above only works for UDP transport. When using TCP, Graylog expects a Nullbyte as message delimiter. This is currently not possible with rsyslog."
Your example should however work via udp.

A word of advice, I would definitely recommend checking out rsyslog filter rules as message processing will continue with your example (check out the tilde character).

Answer (score 0):

Lifted From: https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/tutorials/gelf_forwarding.html

When using TCP, Graylog expects a Nullbyte as message delimiter. So, to use TCP, you need to change delimiter via TCP_FrameDelimiter option.

```
action(type="omfwd" target="graylogserver" port="12201" protocol="tcp" template="gelf" TCP_FrameDelimiter="0" KeepAlive="on")
```